# Linear Schedule of the entropy coefficient in A2C stable baselines

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I have seen in stable baselines that is possible to evaluate a linear schedule in order to constantly decrease the learning rate during training.

I was wondering if there is any implementation in stable baselines where one can use the linear schedule in order to decrease the entropy coefficient in A2C model during training.

Any help would be much appreciated.